# How do I check to see how many characters of a string match up with another string?

Tags: python

I am looking to create a function that checks against a random string of characters to see if it matches with the quote and if not how many matching characters the two have. This is my code so far, I just need a pointer to see how it's done? Thanks.

```
 import random 
 import string

 def genRandText(stringLength=62):
        """Generate a random string of fixed length """
     letters = string.ascii_lowercase
     return ''.join(random.choice(letters + " " + ".") for i in range(stringLength))
##This is a 28 character alphabet from the importation of random 

 y = genRandText()
 TargetString = "he who seeks rest finds boredom. he who seeks work finds rest"
 print (genRandText())
```

This is what outputs in the image when the code is executed, it is random every-time. [Outputted Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lxU56.png)
There is no input needed.

Comment: Can we have some input and output examples to better understand your requirement ?

Comment: Yeah sure, one sec.

Comment: Yeah ok it prints a random string, that's pretty clear. But what do you **want to do** with that string exactly? It is not clear from the question. What output are you **expecting**?

Comment: What is the role of `TargetString` ?

Comment: No images of text please. It's also not really clear to me what is input and what's output. And fix the indentation of your code.

Comment: Basically every character in the random string needs to be checked against TargetString to see how many characters match up. If that makes sense??

Answer (score 1):

> Basically every character in the random string needs to be checked against TargetString to see how many characters match up

Working from this requirement, you can just use a python `set` to keep track of the characters in your `TargetString` and check how many of those are present in the random string.

```py
target_string_chars = set(TargetString)
char_counter = 0
for rand_char in getRandText():
    if rand_char in target_string_chars:
        char_counter = char_counter + 1

print(char_counter)
```

You can even shorten the loop to a list comprehension for brevity

```py
char_counter = len([c for c in getRandText() if c in target_string_chars])
```

Comment: Thank you! Very helpful.